# plsql oracle prevent the use of special characters in the 2nd char of string

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-like

```
create or replace function MyFunction(v_FileName in varchar2)
```

I want to prevent the use of special characters in the 2nd char in v_FileName.

these characters are:

!@#$%^&*()_+=`~[]{}'\|?/><,;:

(i want to allow the use of . and ")

i've tried several regexp_like expressions but no luck.
example:

```
DECLARE
  vResult NUMBER DEFAULT NULL;
BEGIN    
  select case when regexp_like('d[av inder 1234' ,'^[[:alnum:]]([^[:alnum:]]|\"+|\.+)') then 0 else 1 end into vintResult from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('result: '||vintResult);
END;
```

output:

```
result: 1
```

result should be 0 becaue the char [ is supposed to be disallowed.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the colons around the first character class, `[[alnum]]`:

```
'^[[:alnum:]]([^[:alnum:]]|\"+|\.+)'
```

e.g.

```
select case when regexp_like('d[av inder 1234',
  '^[[:alnum:]]([^[:alnum:]]|\"+|\.+)')
    then 0 else 1 end as vintResult from dual;

VINTRESULT
----------
         0
```

Or:

```
DECLARE
  vintResult NUMBER DEFAULT NULL;
BEGIN    
  select case when regexp_like('d[av inder 1234' ,'^[[:alnum:]]([^[:alnum:]]|\"+|\.+)') then 0 else 1 end into vintResult from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('result: '||vintResult);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

result: 0
```

If you're allowing any character in the first position you could just use a dot:

```
'^.([^[:alnum:]]|\"+|\.+)'
```

... but I suspect you do only want alphanumerics in the first position. And if you have a list of specific characters to exclude then it might be clearer, particularly for someone maintaining this in the future, to list those out instead of using the second character class - as in @KevinEsche's answer. (I'm not sure the pattern you have quite matches what you said you wanted to ban anyway).

```
DECLARE
  vintResult NUMBER DEFAULT NULL;
BEGIN    
  select case when regexp_like('d[av inder 1234' ,'^.[][!@#$%^&*()_+=`~{}''\|?/><,;:].*')
    then 0 else 1 end into vintResult from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('result: '||vintResult);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

result: 0
```

Notice the placement of the square brackets within the group of characters, which have moved from your original string; that's to prevent them being misinterpreted as ending the group early.

Comment: editted the coluns in.
i do have them in my code but forgot to write them in here.
still deosn't work though.
how do i work with a list of chars to disallow? what pattern should i use?

Comment: @DrorCohen - your code runs as expected with the columns (with the variable name declaration fixed,anyway). So no idea what you are doing differently.

Comment: i tested the pattern you're suggesting " ^[[:alnum:]]([^[:alnum:]]|\"+|\.+)' "
when changing the char from [ to " i'm still getting result: 0 but it should be 1 because " is allowed

Comment: @DrorCohen - well, I've shown your code and sample value working with that pattern and Kevin's. Maybe the string you're checking doesn't break the rules.

Comment: :(
'd[av inder 1234' definately shouldn't work.
but 'd"av inder 1234' or 'd.av inder 1234' do need to work

Comment: @DrorCohen - right, and your pattern is broken later, as I suggested. That wasn't what you originaly asked about. [Here's an SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/15834) with more sample values, and you can add more of your own, which shows that your pattern wasn't right anyway - though (with the colons) it did work for the example you gave. As you can see, Kevin's approach does work for all those values.

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply just use it like this.

Use a `[]` to define a group of character that should be matched

```
select case when regexp_like('d''v inder 1234' ,'^.[][!@#$%^&*()_+=`~{}''\|?/><,;:].*') then 0 else 1 end from dual;
```